# Drupal 8 extending ListStringItem class. Custom field Type

Tags: drupal

in D8 i'm trying to build custom field, by extending existing "List (text)" field, controlled by "ListStringItem" class.

In my custom module I've created file: src/Plugin/Field/FieldType/MyField.php
In this file I've added:

```
namespace Drupal\my_field\Plugin\Field\FieldType;

use Drupal\Component\Utility\Unicode;
use Drupal\Core\Field\FieldStorageDefinitionInterface;
use Drupal\Core\TypedData\DataDefinition;

/**
 * Plugin implementation of the 'list_string' field type.
 *
 * @FieldType(
 *   id = "my_field",
 *   label = @Translation("My List (text)"),
 *   description = @Translation("This field stores text values from a list of allowed roles 'value => label' pairs, i.e. 'US States': IL => Illinois, IA => Iowa, IN => Indiana."),
 *   category = @Translation("Text"),
 *   default_widget = "options_select",
 *   default_formatter = "list_default",
 * )
 */

 class MyField extends ListStringItem {
.....
```

However i'm getting below error:

> Class 'Drupal\my_field\Plugin\Field\FieldType\ListStringItem' not found in..

So as is see my module is searching for the class inside my module. I can't find the way to tell him that this class is in **Drupal\options\Plugin\Field\FieldType\ListStringItem**

Answer (score 0):

So when I've added below code:

> use Drupal\options\Plugin\Field\FieldType\ListStringItem;

The error is gone.